# How to change background color height when mouse hover on the tab in Vuetify.js components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuetify.js

I have to change background color height when mouse hover tabs menu.
Its my customer order, I tried to make code below.
It seems success but a little bit wired movement in tab.

I used v-tab:hover to control tab's height.
When mouse hover on the tab, tab's title move to up.
I want to fix tab's title and just background color adjust.
Could someone advise me, please?

[Html]

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-tabs>
      <v-tab>Item One</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Item Two</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Item Three</v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

[CSS]

```
.v-tab:hover {
  height: 40px;
}
```

[Javascript]

```
 new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
})
```

Comment: `.v-tab` implies something with a class of v-tab ... guess you could give your `<v-tab>` that class ... e.g. `<v-tab class="v-tab">....</v-tab>`

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I have tried your advise, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `<v-hover>` component is the correct way to do this.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-tabs>
      <v-hover v-slot="{ hover }">
        <v-tab :class="{ 'on-hover': hover }">Item One</v-tab>
      </v-hover>
      <v-hover v-slot="{ hover }">
        <v-tab :class="{ 'on-hover': hover }">Item Two</v-tab>
      </v-hover>
      <v-hover v-slot="{ hover }">
        <v-tab :class="{ 'on-hover': hover }">Item Three</v-tab>
      </v-hover>
    </v-tabs>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.v-tab.on-hover {
  /* hover styles here */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are some other CSS overwriting the height your code should work since v-tab is a class of the `<v-tab>`.
See codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-pike-kp3ru?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

or code below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-tabs>
      <v-tab>Item One</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Item Two</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Item Three</v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.v-tab, .v-tab:hover {
  height: 40px;
}
</style>
```

Edit: Added same CSS to .v-tab without hover to avoid the movement on hover.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!! I really appreciate it!

Comment: so, functionally identical code works ... how suspicious